# How to get value in column "About me" of Sharepoint Group programmatically

Tags: groups

I try to get the value in column "About me" of Sharepoint group. But It always empty.
I'm using Sharepoint server 2013, my account is site administrator.
[image: Get value from "About me"]

My code to get:

```
 var groups = SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.Groups;
                foreach (SPGroup item in groups)
                {
                    litMessage.Text += item.Name + "#" + item.Description;
                }
```

And the result: 
[image: Result]

Please help me how to get this value.

**Updated:** 
I cannot get about me of new group (GroupPR&CC). The default group (Approvers, Designers...) is ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the below code to get the description:

```
var groups = SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.Groups;
foreach (SPGroup group in groups)
{
    SPListItem groupItem = web.SiteUserInfoList.GetItemById(group.ID);
    litMessage.Text += group.Name + "#" + groupItem["Notes"];
}
```

If its a single group, use it as below:

```
SPGroup g = web.SiteGroups["GroupName"];
SPFieldMultiLineText text = (SPFieldMultiLineText)web.SiteUserInfoList.Fields[SPBuiltInFieldId.Notes];
SPListItem groupItem = web.SiteUserInfoList.GetItemById(g.ID);
var description = groupItem["Notes"]
```